# The secondary meaning of the word cheerful

Tags: meaning

According to Oxford Learner's Dictionary(http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cheerful), the secondary meaning of the word *cheerful* is:
*giving you a feeling of happiness*:

Examples:
1) a bright, cheerful restaurant.

2) walls painted in cheerful (= light and bright) colours.

3) a chatty, cheerful letter.

All these examples are about inanimate objects.
Can the meaning not be applied to a person?

Answer (score 2):

No. The secondary sense is only possible with inanimate objects, because they are incapable of feeling happy.

In theory you could describe someone as *cheerful*, intending to mean that she causes you to feel happy.

> Anne's such a cheerful woman I am always happy to work with her.

But in practice you would always be **understood** to mean that she was *cheerful* herself—full of cheer, happy—precisely because that is the primary sense, which is specific to people.

To my ear, this is true of a letter, too: if you tell me you got a *cheerful* letter from your sister I would assume you meant that the letter expressed *her* happiness and good spirits, not that it caused *your* happiness and good spirits.

Comment: "*But in practice you would always be understood to mean that she was cheerful herself—full of cheer, happy—precisely because that is the primary sense, which is specific to people.*"

This does not prevent her from causing you to feel happy, does it?

Comment: @MakotoKato Not at all. But it prevents you from using the word *cheerful* to describe that if you wish to be understood.